# Baby boy, preterm birth weight 1.5 kg, needs development help at 18 months

Tags: toddler, language-development, premature, motor-development

My baby boy was preterm (8.5 months) and low birth weight (1.5 kg).  Currently, at 18 months, he is able to stand alone but still not started walking. He is not able to speak more than 3-4 words like "mother", "father", and "sis".

Please suggest what we can do for baby development. 
**I am worried for his future because rumors says he need special school, He is not able to speak properly.**

Comment: Welcome to Parenting.SE! Have you taken your son to a doctor and asked your questions? There is no way to get a child to reach his developmental milestones sooner, but early intervention for some delays (for example, perhaps he does not hear well and so it is harder to learn to speak) help. I also hope you can narrow what you're asking -- do you want to know _what is normal for an 18-month-old?_, or more _what are our next steps?_

Answer (score 3):

Early intervention from speech-language therapists, occupational therapists, and physical therapists, can be very, very helpful.  Are these available where you live?  A good place to find out would be by talking with a doctor or nurse.

I think you are doing the right thing by questioning whether his development is everything it could be.

Reading between the lines of your post, it sounds like there is a special school available where you live.  That is good news, because if your baby has any significant delays, a special school could be very helpful.

The baby of a friend of mine started early intervention at approximately your baby's age.  When he started, he had significant delays.  Now, if you were just meeting him for the first time (age 4), you wouldn't guess he had extra challenges in the beginning.

Take heart.